# Cumulative return over x-days for specific dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` `df1` with daily returns (1+r) and I try to calculate cumulative returns over 4 days for specific dates from a `list` called `dates` and assign them to a new `DataFrame` `df2`. Is there an efficient way to do that with pandas?

```
df1:
            Return
Date    
2022-01-01  1.03
2022-01-02  0.98
2022-01-03  1.01
2022-01-04  0.99
2022-01-05  1.01
2022-01-06  0.93
2022-01-07  0.96
2022-01-08  0.92
2022-01-09  1.03
2022-01-10  1.05
2022-01-11  1.08
2022-01-12  1.02

dates = ['2022-01-02', '2022-01-05', '2022-01-09', '2022-01-10']
```

I try to get df2 with the cumulative returns for the specific dates over 4 days. As an example for 2022-01-02: 0.9897 = 0.98 * 1.01 * 0.99 * 1.01

```
            CumReturn
Date    
2022-01-02  0.9897
2022-01-05  0.8296
2022-01-09  1.1914
2022-01-10  1.1567
```

Thanks a lot for your suggestion!

Comment: I think the value for 2022-01-09 should be  1.03

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For 2022-01-09 I try to get 1.1914 = 1.03*1.05*1.08*1.02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute a bottom-up rolling window product with a window size of 4 (or whatever you need). With `min_periods=1`, it computes all values, even if the window is smaller than the target value of 4, which seems to be necessary here (otherwise, `2022-01-10` would be `NaN` because there are only 3 values).

```py
df2 = df.Return[::-1].rolling(4, min_periods=1).agg(lambda x:x.prod())[::-1].loc[dates]
```

This results in this series:

```py
>>> df2
Date
2022-01-02    0.989701
2022-01-05    0.829590
2022-01-09    1.191380
2022-01-10    1.156680
Name: Return, dtype: float64
```

To turn it into a dataframe, do `df2.to_frame('CumReturn')`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly that I was trying!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and [`GroupBy.prod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.prod.html):

```
g = pd.cut(pd.to_datetime(df1.index),
           bins=pd.to_datetime(dates+['2199-01-01']),
           labels=dates,
           right=False)

out = df1.groupby(g)['Return'].prod()
```

output:

```
2022-01-02    0.979902
2022-01-05    0.829590
2022-01-09    1.030000
2022-01-10    1.156680
Name: Return, dtype: float64
```

Comment: How do you define the number of days to compute the cumulative return? What if it is 5 for example?